# Execute.EmbeddedScript timeout exceeded

Tags: sql-server, fluent-migrator

I have a migration that runs an embedded SQL script that can take some significant amount of time to execute.

When I run the script from MSSM, it runs fine,

When I run the migration, I get an error:

The error was Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.

I've not been able to find where I can adjust the timeout value. Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a timeout parameter that you can pass into Migrate.exe - https://github.com/schambers/fluentmigrator/wiki/Command-Line-Runner-Options

There is a timeout parameter for the Nant and MsBuild runners as well.

Does that help?

Comment: Yes.  Sorry for taking so long to get back to you.  (Holidays).